# Removing or preventing duplicate template matches in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a map on which there is a number of similar symbols (trees) spread across the map. I
I'm using opencv to find the X,Y coordinates of all the symbols.

It's working well but I am getting a huge number of duplicate results. If I increase the filter threshold the number of duplicates is reduced by lots of the symbols are missed. I've tried writing some code to filter out results based on proximity but I'm not having much luck. Does anyone have any insight into what I could try here?

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('images/map.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('images/tree.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.35
matches = np.where( res >= threshold)

tree_count = 0
for pt in matches:
    tree_count += 1
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (255,0,0), 1)

cv2.imwrite('found_map.jpg',img_rgb)
print "Done " + map
```

Answer (score 16):

You can keep track of the regions of the image where you already detected a tree (using a mask). Then you only increase the tree counter if, for example, the center of each match was not marked yet.

Code:

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('trees.png')
template = cv2.imread('apple_tree.png')
h, w = template.shape[:2]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.95
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

tree_count = 0
mask = np.zeros(img_rgb.shape[:2], np.uint8)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    if mask[pt[1] + int(round(h/2)), pt[0] + int(round(w/2))] != 255:
        mask[pt[1]:pt[1]+h, pt[0]:pt[0]+w] = 255
        tree_count += 1
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,0), 1)

cv2.imwrite('found_map.jpg',img_rgb)
print("Found {} trees in total!".format(tree_count))
```

**Before** (not removing duplicates):
[image]

[image]

**After**  (removing duplicates with mask):
[image]
[image]

You can notice in the bottom image the thinner green lines illustrating that we detected 3 apple trees instead of 13!

Comment: If w/2 or h/2 is not integer you will get an error. Just fix it with round(w/2) and round(h/2) and you will be ready to go again...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

1. Do a morphological [erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) of the result image until you only have points. Many modules have this function. for example opencv and skimage.
2. Using the result image, you can try calculate contours and extract the inside of each contour.

Without some sample data, it's hard to say what will be the best option. Different data often require different approaches.